# How to fix wp_remote_get() error // get value from an array?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to get each `Bank_name` on WordPress from the array while calling an external Api. I used `wp_remote_get()`. While doing the `foreach` loop with the array, I got this error:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach().

To debug the error, I tried echoing first one `Bank_name` by providing an index. I did exact same thing in two ways but one works and the other one doesn't. The only difference is that, one way uses `wp_remote_get()`, while other one uses the response as an array without calling any api.

Where is the error coming from?

This doesn't work:

```
    $request = wp_remote_get( 'https://tv-api-dev.azurewebsites.net/api/GetBankInfo' );
    if( is_wp_error( $request ) ) {
        return false; 
    }

    $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );
    $test = json_decode( $body, true );

    print_r($test) ; 
    echo $test[0]["Bank_name"];
```

The following works fine:

```
$someJSON = "[\r\n {\r\n \"Bank_id\": 1,\r\n \"Bank_name\": \"Aktia Pankki\"\r\n },\r\n {\r\n \"Bank_id\": 2,\r\n \"Bank_name\": \"Bigbank\"\r\n },\r\n {\r\n \"Bank_id\": 3,\r\n \"Bank_name\": \"POP Pankit\"\r\n },\r\n {\r\n \"Bank_id\": 4,\r\n \"Bank_name\": \"Bonum Pankki\"\r\n },\r\n {\r\n \"Bank_id\": 5,\r\n \"Bank_name\": \"Citibank\"\r\n },\r\n {\r\n \"Bank_id\": 6,\r\n \"Bank_name\": \"Danske Bank\"\r\n },\r\n {\r\n \"Bank_id\": 8,\r\n \"Bank_name\": \"DNB BANK ASA\"\r\n },\r\n {\r\n \"Bank_id\": 9,\r\n \"Bank_name\": \"Handelsbanken\"\r\n },\r\n {\r\n \"Bank_id\": 10,\r\n \"Bank_name\": \"Holvi\"\r\n },\r\n {\r\n \"Bank_id\": 11,\r\n \"Bank_name\": \"Nordea Pankki\"\r\n },\r\n {\r\n \"Bank_id\": 12,\r\n \"Bank_name\": \"OP Ryhmä\"\r\n },\r\n {\r\n \"Bank_id\": 13,\r\n \"Bank_name\": \"S-Pankki\"\r\n },\r\n {\r\n \"Bank_id\": 14,\r\n \"Bank_name\": \"Swedbank\"\r\n },\r\n {\r\n \"Bank_id\": 15,\r\n \"Bank_name\": \"Säästöpankki\"\r\n },\r\n {\r\n \"Bank_id\": 16,\r\n \"Bank_name\": \"Alandsbanken\"\r\n }\r\n]";

  // Convert JSON string to Array
  $someArray = json_decode($someJSON, true);
   print_r($someArray);        // Dump all data of the Array
  echo $someArray[0]["Bank_name"]; // Access Array data
  echo $someArray[0]["Bank_id"]; // Access Array data
```

From 2nd way, I get output Aktia Pankki1, which is what I expect also from the 1st way but I get this message:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'Bank_name' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wpsummerproject\wp-content\themes\astra\functions.php
>   on line 181

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the data from the given URL. Not sure why but in the first `json_decode()`, the obtained value is the single JSON object with sub items. When that value is again called with `json_decode()` then value is obtained as an array. You may want to check in the source first how data is converted to JSON. There seems to be the problem.

```
$request = wp_remote_get( 'https://tv-api-dev.azurewebsites.net/api/GetBankInfo' );
if( is_wp_error( $request ) ) {
    return false;
}

$body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );
$body_content = json_decode( $body, true );
$details = json_decode( $body_content, true );
print_r( $details[0]['Bank_name']);
print_r( $details[0]['Bank_id']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$url      = 'https://tv-api-dev.azurewebsites.net/api/GetBankInfo';

$response = wp_remote_get( esc_url_raw( $url ) );

/* Will result in $api_response being an array of data,
parsed from the JSON response of the API listed above */

$api_response = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ), true );
```

This is an example from codex.wordpress.org
Your link: https://tv-api-dev.azurewebsites.net/api/GetBankInfo goes to a valid json. Should work.

Answer (score 0):

This will work in your case,

```
$request = wp_remote_get( 'https://tv-api-dev.azurewebsites.net/api/GetBankInfo' );
if( is_wp_error( $request ) ) {
    return false; 
}

$body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );
$test = json_decode( $body,true );
$test = json_decode($test,true);

echo $test[0]['Bank_name'];
```